Auto select a value from a filter
I've a Tableau dashboard with two single-value filters - one for category and the other for the products. Each category has multiple products.
The filter for category is set to "all values in database" and the filter for product is set to "only relevant values". Basically whenever I change an option from the category filter, the product filter is modified to the correct set of items but nothing gets selected by default. And because of this I get a blank space in my worksheet until I manually select an option from the product filter.
Is there a way such that whenever I toggle between the category filter, the first value from the product filter gets automatically selected?
